# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, nutch

I'm trying to run Nutch 2.2.1 using Cygwin64/Windows7 and getting the following error:

```
MY-PC /home/apache-nutch-2.2.1/src/bin
$ ./nutch crawl urls -dir test -depth 3 -topN 4
cygpath: can't convert empty path
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler
```

Has anyone seen or resolved this error before?

Answer (score 0):

It shows that the CLASSPATH for your executable is incorrect. Please verify your CLASSPATH. Note that Unix/Linux style paths and Windows style paths (cygpath) are different.

Hopes this helps.